# How to remove "<" from value in xml

Tags: xml, xslt, html-escape-characters

In my xml there are such xml tags:

```
<field>&lt;</field>
```

I need to replace the "<" character with blank.
I tried this statement but it prompts an error.

```
<xsl:value-of select="replace(.//field, '\&lt;', '')"/>
```

Error.
Unable to generate the XML document using the provided XML/XSL input. Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation

How can I do it?

Comment: "but it prompts an error" - please specify the exact error

Comment: Unable to generate the XML document using the provided XML/XSL input. Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation

Comment: Please edit that into the question - and it sounds like there should be more detailed errors available (the ones "reported during stylesheet compilation").

Comment: (Additionally, please don't include "Regards" and a signature on posts. Those are regarded as noise, hence why I edited them out...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear whether you use an XSLT 1 processor where the XPath 2 function `replace` is simply not supported or whether the error is from the attempt to use the backslash or the attempt to call the `replace` function on several `field` element, in any case it should suffice to use

```
<xsl:template match="field">
  <xsl:value-of select="translate(., '&lt;', '')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

in any XSLT version or

```
<xsl:template match="field">
  <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '&lt;', '')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

in XSLT 2 or later.